# Anyone with and Idea how to fix app.use is not a function after installing Element-plus using npm in vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

So after installing Vue 3.0 based component library (Element-Plus) in my project using npm install element-plus --save, I get this error that says app.use is not a function.
I have also imported Element fully like so:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus'
import 'element-plus/dist/index.css'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import "./assets/Css/Style.css"
app.use(ElementPlus)
createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app').
```

But I get the under-listed error.
Uncaught TypeError: app.use is not a function

Comment: You're calling `app.use()` but `app` doesn't exist yet. You'll probably need something like `const app = createApp();` first.

Comment: Looking at the code again, it's probably as simple as `createApp(App).use(router).use(ElementPlus).mount('#app');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize Vue with `createApp()`, before you can use `.use`. Like this:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus'
import 'element-plus/dist/index.css'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import "./assets/Css/Style.css"
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(ElementPlus)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app').
```